# ActiveMQ throttling consumer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

i want to do a throttling to a consumer of some queue in the activeMQ, in hornetq (of jboss, this is do it with annotations on the definition of the mdb Consumer). I can't find any similar in the documentation of activemq, the closest that i find was this

```
consumer.recvDelay   0 ms    Pause consumer for recvDelay milliseconds with each message (allows consumer throttling).
```

from: http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html

But there i can't find how i can do it in java.

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

EDIT: Here is the ActiveMQManager code and the consumer code:

```
public class ActiveMQManager {

    private static ActiveMQConnectionFactory CONNECTION_FACTORY;

    public static Connection CONNECTION;

    public static Session SESSION;

    public static Destination TEST_QUEUE;

    public static void start() {
        try {

            CONNECTION_FACTORY = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

            CONNECTION = CONNECTION_FACTORY.createConnection();
            CONNECTION.start();

            SESSION = CONNECTION.createSession(false,
                    Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            TestClient testClient = new TestClient();

            TEST_QUEUE = SESSION.createQueue("TEST.QUEUE");

            MessageConsumer testConsumer = SESSION.createConsumer(TEST_QUEUE);
            test.setMessageListener(testClient);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public static void stop() {
        try {
            // Clean up
            SESSION.close();
            CONNECTION.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer code is very simple (for this example):

```
public class TestConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //Do something with the message
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your consumer code/config?

Comment: ok, i will add it to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this depends on the consumer technology being used...but here are a few options

- you can manually introduce a delay in your consumer code (not an exact science but this will limit the throughput)
- you can also control the number of threads that your consumer uses by setting maxConcurrentConsumers property of you JMS connection...that said, this won't throttle message throughput, just limit the level of concurrency being used by your consumer
- better yet, you can set the exact number of messages to consume per time period using a throttler EIP implementation

  for example, this is trivial using the [Camel Throttler](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html)

  `from("activemq:queueA").throttle(10).to("activemq:queueB")`

Comment: yeah, we are using sleep in the thread to do the delay, it's ugly, for that i star this question, camel seem's interesting, but we don't time (now) do implement that solution, but in the future maybe we do it.

Comment: anyway, thx for the answer, it's help to keep searching for a solution

Comment: okey. thx for your comments boday, anyway i still can't prove the "camel" solution but seem's to be the best answer, congrats, you have the bounty :)

Comment: @boday Is your solution working without setting a prefetch limit? I don't think so and wonder whether the answer should be amended.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt - it works w/o needing to set prefetch explicitly (defaults to 1k for queues)...you can definitely change it and see different throughput, but it's not required to change it to throttle a consumer from a queue, etc.

Answer (score 3):

With ActiveMQ you can set the consumer prefetch limit: http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

To configure it, you can use the connection URL (most of the configurations can be done using the URL) or the Java API.

For more interesting parameters: http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html

Comment: prefetch limit only controls the algorithm of sending/buffering messages on the consumer, not the rate of consumption...

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that Camel Throttler keeps the exchanges in-memory while they are blocked by the Throttler. So, if you have 100 queue consumers and the Server (exposing the SOAP service) is slow, you may have in-memory up to 100 exchanges!

Posted this question for this: [Throttle consumption rate of all JMS consumers listening on an ActiveMQ queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462059/throttle-consumption-rate-of-all-jms-consumers-listening-on-an-activemq-queue)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your statement: _"I was wondering if there an ActiveMQ feature to impose the throttle requirement on the ActiveMQ level."_ appears to be a question. If the existing answers do not help, please ask a new question. Or, if I am misunderstanding your answer, please consider rewording.