# ActiveMQ rate limit external service

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue

Let's say we have some web crawling system which needs to scale to many workers.
Each worker has a limit for example max. 5 HTTP requests per minute per web host that could be crawled.

"per web host" can be in message header and which will be populated by producer.

Can I teach ActiveMQ to dispatch messages to nodes in this fasion?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ does not support consumer throttling, only producer throttling. Camel *does* support this though, see the accepted answer here: [ActiveMQ throttling consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258755/activemq-throttling-consumer)

Comment: The Camel Throttler has very limited options. I need to limis "per time period per web host that could be crawled". Using Camel Throttler I can limit only queue throughput over time. I also need to do it per web host or other message header value.

Comment: Sounds like your have to roll your own :( You could still queue up the processing requests via ActiveMQ, use queues to sort them by site, and dispatch them to workers. Part of the message could be a throttling limit, in which you use java timing and synchronization primitives to achieve your desired scrape rate.

Most everything is designed to run "As fast as possible" :) Kinda rare you have a problem of the opposite