# Throttle consumption rate of all JMS consumers listening on an ActiveMQ queue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

Using Camel Throttler component you can define an upper limit on the rate of consumed messages per time period, e.g.:

```
from("activemq:queueA").throttle(10).to("direct-vm:bla")
```

What I see as non ideal is that Camel Throttler keeps the exchanges in-memory while they are blocked by the Throttler. So, if you have 100 queue consumers and for any reason the "direct-vm:bla" is slow (e.g. invoking external slow service), you may have in-memory up to 100 exchanges!

I was wondering if there is an ActiveMQ feature to impose the throttling requirement on the ActiveMQ level. Maybe even on a per queue level. Something similar to consumer-max-rate of HornetQ.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the consumer to use a transaction (doesn't have to be an XA transaction. If you only have 1 other endpoint use a local JMS transaction. see: LLR transaction approach). If the Camel route fails, the messages roll back to the broker.

Comment: thx for the answer Matt, but how this would help me do the throttling?

Comment: You'd have to elaborate on the reason to add the throttling. Typically, I don't want to add a throttle to an already slow consumer. If you just want to add a throttle.. add it into the transacted route. If the route or last endpoint fails, the message still rolls back to the broker-- even if it has been throttled.

Comment: Regarding the reason is because of the agreement with the third party exposing the Web Service that the camel route is calling.

What you propose would do the trick in the sense that if for any reason the route fails the messages will be rolled back to the ActiveMQ queue and will be consumed again. I agree on this.

But I was hoping of finding a way to impose the throttling on the ActiveMQ level and not in the Camel Route level.

Comment: @Vassilis Did you find away to impose the throttling on the ActiveMQ level? I am looking for the same.

Comment: @Bhuvan Unfortunately last time I checked (end of 2016) that was not possible. Depending on your scenario/ requirements there may be workarounds. E.g. as Matt Pavlovich mentioned you may consume as part of a local or global transaction and throw an exception to rollback and re-consume under certain conditions. For example if you call an external rest service you may exploit Circuit Breaker and when the circuit opens you can rollback the transaction.

Comment: @Vassilis totally understand the need to throttle to rate limit to 3rd party Web Service. However, I do not understand the need to have it in the broker. Sounds to me to be a technical requirement of the integration from broker to 3rd party web service (abide by 3rd party Web Service SLA), and you'd want to keep that requirement encapsulated in the route. Pushing it into the broker means you'd rely on other from of documentation for the next coder to know that's a technical requirement of the integration.